# TabBarController with Coordinators (MVVM-C) - Opening the same ViewController in different tabs

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uitabbarcontroller, coordinator-pattern

I have a TabBarCoordinator with 2 tabs: One for a list of movies (`MoviesListViewController`) with `FirstTabCoordinator`, and one for favorite movies (`FavoritesViewController`) with `SecondTabCoordinator`, both with a tableView, and each tab has its own `navigationController`.
When I tap on a movie, in the movie list tab or favorites tab, I push the `MovieDetailsViewController`. This works fine. But in the MovieDetailsViewController I have another collection of Similar Movies.

**My problem is:** 
In MovieDetailsViewController, when I tap on a similar movie, on `didSelectItemAt indexPath`, how do I tell in which coordinator to push the next MovieDetailsViewController? Because I can get to movie details from both coordinators.

I think I may have to add some sort of mechanism between those 2 coordinators, but I'm not sure.

**This is my MainCoordinator**

```
protocol Coordinator {
  func startCoordinator()
}
    
class MainCoordinator: Coordinator {
  var tabBarController = UITabBarController()
  
  static func getCoordinator() -> MainCoordinator? {
    if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first, let delegate = scene.delegate as? SceneDelegate {
      return delegate.coordinator
    }
    return nil
  }
  
  func startCoordinator() {
    FirstTabCoordinator.shared.startCoordinator()
    let moviesListVC = FirstTabCoordinator.shared.moviesListViewController
    self.setupTabBarItem(vc: moviesListVC,
                     title: "All Movies",
                     imageName: "film",
                     selectedImageName: "film.fill")
    
    SecondTabCoordinator.shared.startCoordinator()
    let favoritesVC = SecondTabCoordinator.shared.favoritesViewController
    self.setupTabBarItem(vc: favoritesVC,
                     title: "Favorites",
                     imageName: "heart",
                     selectedImageName: "heart.fill")
    
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.barStyle = .black
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = .white
    
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [FirstTabCoordinator.shared.navigationController,
                                             SecondTabCoordinator.shared.navigationController]
  }
 
  func setupTabBarItem(vc: UIViewController, title: String, imageName: String, selectedImageName: String) {
    let defaultImage = UIImage(systemName: imageName)
    let selectedImage = UIImage(systemName: selectedImageName)
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: title, image: defaultImage, selectedImage: selectedImage)
    vc.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
  }
}
```

**First Tab coordinator:**

```
class FirstTabCoordinator: Coordinator {
  var navigationController: UINavigationController! {
    didSet {
      navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
      navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }
  }
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
  private lazy var navigationManager = NavigationManager(self.navigationController)
  
  static let shared = FirstTabCoordinator()
  private init() {}
  
  lazy var moviesListViewController: MoviesTableViewController = {
    let viewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MoviesTableViewController") as! MoviesTableViewController
    viewController.title = "All Movies"
    return viewController
  }()
  
  func startCoordinator() {
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController()
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = [self.moviesListViewController]
  }
  
  func goToMovieDetails(movie: Movie) {
    self.navigationManager.goToMovieDetails(movie: movie)
  }
}
```

**Second Tab Coordinator:**

```
class SecondTabCoordinator: Coordinator {
  var navigationController: UINavigationController! {
    didSet {
      navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
      navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }
  }
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
  private lazy var navigationManager = NavigationManager(self.navigationController)

  static let shared = SecondTabCoordinator()
  private init() {}
  
  lazy var favoritesViewController: FavoritesViewController = {
    let viewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FavoritesViewController") as FavoritesViewController
    viewController.title = "Favorites"
    return viewController
  }()
  
  func goToMovieDetails(movie: Movie) {
    self.navigationManager.goToMovieDetails(movie: movie)
  }
  
  func startCoordinator() {
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController()
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = [self.favoritesViewController]
  }
}
```

Comment: You should have a protocol  MovieCoordinator that contains the différents methods  like show movie details that both first a second protocols implement. So the detail movie controller does not have to know which coordinator to use as it is it’s associated one which handles it. MovieCoordinator could also be a class to be subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make the coordinator implement a protocol that contains your function `func goToMovieDetails(movie: Movie)` and pass in an instance of it when creating the ViewController so you don't care if it is First or Second Tab coordinator

Comment: I end up using .selectedIndex for tabController to determine in which tab I am, but your solution also helped me. Thanks!